# ASP.NET MVC5 OAuth, why second prompt asking for email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

When I OAuth into my ASP.NET MVC5 app, there is a second dialog that comes up after I've confirmed my google account (for example).  It says:

> You've successfully authenticated with Google. Please enter a user
>   name for this site below and click the Register button to finish
>   logging in.

I want to get the email from google as an extended attribute (I found posts how to do that) and I want to use that email instead of prompting the user for it.  How do I do that an disable this extra screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second step is only there as an example of how to collect additional user data before creating the user account and associating the login with it. If you don't want it, remove it. Just merge the code there that actually creates the user account into the `ExternalLoginCallback` action, where it currently redirects to this second step.

Comment: makes sense.  slowly making sense of this.

Comment: how to disable it (I'm new to ASP.NET)